# Cannot convert method group to non-delegate type 'bool'

Tags: c#

full error:
Cannot convert method group 'CombinationCheck' to non-delegate type 'bool'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

I'm trying to use the value from a bool to determine the value of a text box but can't seem to work out how to do it. Any help is greatly appreciated, I get the error from (CombinationCheck)

```
bool CombinationCheck(string combination)
{
    if (combination.Length > 5)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

and

```
if (CombinationCheck)      
        text_SafeStatus.Text = "Combination Set";
    else 
        text_SafeStatus.Text = "Combination Not Set";
```

Comment: i already answered this in your previous question..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`CombinationCheck` is a method, that requires one (string) parameter. SO you cannot reference it by name alone. You must include the required string parameter (`combination`).

```
if (CombinationCheck(someString))      
    text_SafeStatus.Text = "Combination Set";
else 
    text_SafeStatus.Text = "Combination Not Set";
```

or

```
text_SafeStatus.Text = 
    CombinationCheck(someString)? "Combination Set": 
                                  "Combination Not Set";
```